# uploading a file that you have uploaded into the database

Tags: php, database

is there a way to upload a file that the user have uploaded before into the database? eg, you have uploaded a resume into your own profile page (online) and now, you would like to send this same resume (online) to another person by uploading to the same website. however, it has to be chosen from your profile page

Comment: I don't think that it's a smart idea to put file into database.
 Put link to file into database and place file on `FILE SYSTEM` and if you want to send this file to someone else, don't upload it again, just share the link

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but pointless. As @Mubin Khalid said, you should store these resources as files and store their path in the database. The file can be accessed through its path and you need to load only that from the database. If you want to duplicate files, then you have serious problems with the design of your database.

You need to have a table for `resources`, like this: `resources(id, path)`. Naturally, based on your business logic, you might need other columns, like `resource_type` or `owner`. To handle attachments, you need to tackle with the n:m relation types using intermediate tables, which will have a `foreign key` which `references resources(id)`.